# CSS Grid: 50% height not working on second column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to get the rows in the second column of a css grid structure to be 50% in height.

I have this code:

```
grid-template-areas: "green red"
                     "green blue";
grid-template-rows: 100% 50%;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
```

However, the first row in that column is larger. This is the result:

[image]

I tried adding:

```
#page > .red { max-height: 50%; }
```

but this gave me:

[image]

How do I get the two rows in the second column to be 50% height?

## JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/busr380n/13/

```css
#page > .green {
  grid-area: green;
  background-color: green;
}

#page > .red {
  grid-area: red;
  background-color: red;
}

#page > .blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}


#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;

  grid-template-areas: "green red"
                       "green blue";
  grid-template-rows: 100% 50%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;

}

#page > .red { max-height: 50%; }
```

```html
<section id="page">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your code:

```
grid-template-areas: "green red"
                     "green blue";
grid-template-rows:  100% 50%;
```

You've created two rows. But you've given the first row 100% height of the grid container. This forces the second row to exist outside of the container.

Try this instead:

```
grid-template-areas: "green red"
                     "green blue";
grid-template-rows:  50% 50%;
```

No need for the `max-height` on the grid item.

```css
#page {
  display: grid;
  height: 250px;
  grid-template-areas: "green red"
                       "green blue";
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
}

#page > .green {
  grid-area: green;
  background-color: green;
}

#page > .red {
  grid-area: red;
  background-color: red;
}

#page > .blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="page">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I can accept in 6 mins. Thank you :) Much appreciated.